# Force Powerpoint in Presenter Mode on 2nd Monitor

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I wrote a small app for managing/showing Powerpoint Presentations on a Laptop with secondary display. The Problem is, I have very limited to no possibilty changing the Files directly, but need to show them always in presenter mode.

Does anybody know a way (maybe via an undocumented registry key or something like that - I have full access to the presenting laptop) to force Powerpoint always in presenter mode irrespective of what is defined in the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this value in the registry to 1 before starting PowerPoint (changes to the registry made AFTER starting PPT generally won't have any effect):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options
UseMonMgr